# Unable to install Eclipse, how can I locate the missing package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, eclipse

I can't install eclipse with `sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform`

The response is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package eclipse-platform
```

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a; apt-cache policy eclipse-platform` in a terminal?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get update eclipse-platform`

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1158895

Answer (score 1):

One way to install eclipse is through the software center.

[image: Eclipse install]
Another way is to visit http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=luna and compare the different packages,

download the package that meets your needs from 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

and follow the installation instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)